# How can I get the distance using google maps?

Tags: php, cakephp, curl

If you try to get the distance of:

```
Kalyani Nagar, Wadgaon Sheri, Pune, Maharashtra, India
Karve Nagar, Hingne Budrukh, Pune, Maharashtra, India
```

with this URL we get distance as 3.4953372691389 miles

http://www.sudhirhub.com/2010/05/find-distance-between-two-cities-using.html

in `maps.google.com` you get:

```
N Main Road 8.8 mi
```

This distance is by road so the distance is too large.

Is there there any API/Any CURL request that will give me the same distance as that of `maps.google.com`?

Comment: http://www.freemaptools.com/how-far-is-it-between.htm , http://www.daftlogic.com/projects-google-maps-distance-calculator.htm try this

Comment: @ jeni, still it not matches with maps.google.com

Comment: If you need a php based solution for cakephp, you might be looking for this approach:
http://www.dereuromark.de/2012/06/12/geocoding-with-cakephp/ it has a lib and optionally a behavior to geocode just about anything via cakePHP (2.x).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
rad = function(x) {return x*Math.PI/180;}

distHaversine = function(p1, p2) {
  var R = 6371; // earth's mean radius in km
  var dLat  = rad(p2.lat() - p1.lat());
  var dLong = rad(p2.lng() - p1.lng());

  var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
      Math.cos(rad(p1.lat())) * Math.cos(rad(p2.lat())) * Math.sin(dLong/2) *          Math.sin(dLong/2);
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
  var d = R * c;

  return d.toFixed(3);
 }
```

Or use

Make sure you included to your head section.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3&libraries=geometry"></script>
```

and the call will be

```
google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween (latLngA, latLngB);
```

[Refrence](http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#spherical)

Answer (score -1):

Look at the [example here](https://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/#JSON). All you need to do is request that URL and run the results through `json_decode()`. Something like:

```
$result = file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Chicago,IL&destination=Los+Angeles,CA&waypoints=Joplin,MO|Oklahoma+City,OK&sensor=false');
$result = json_decode($results);
$distance = $result->routes->legs->distance['text'];
echo $distance // Outputs: "583 mi"
```